# Why the name "relaxation time"?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, terminology, dissipation

Trying to explain to myself the Stokes number, I was linked by Wikipedia to this article:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relaxation_(physics)

In that article, if $\tau$ is the relaxation time, then after $\tau$ units the systems obtain a factor of $\frac{1}{e}$. I do not understand why in all those systems, a value of $\frac{1}{e}$ would be considered "equilibrium" or "relaxed". Please explain why we use that terminology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We *don't* consider the system "at equilibrium" or "relaxed" once the variable in question has decreased by a factor of $1/\mbox{e}$. However, the relaxation time $\tau$ gives us an order-of-magnitude, i.e. a rough estimate of the time required to "reach equilibrium": Given how fast $\mbox{e}^{-n\,(t/\tau)}$ decays, we expect the system to be essentially at equilibrium within a few times $\tau$. Of course, strictly speaking such systems typically relax asymptotically, and reach exact equilibrium only for $t\rightarrow\infty$.